# Samba shares only work with "force user"

Tags: permissions, samba

I seem to have trouble understanding the configurations of samba on Ubuntu. Let’s say I have 4 folders in /srv, these are media, share, bob-personal, and joe-personal. I also have 3 users: bob, joe, and nas. Users bob and joe are standard users (one of them is disabled in Ubuntu, since I didn’t assign it a password, for both users, their file in AccountsService has an entry “SystemAccount=true”, so they don’t show up on the login screen). nas is the administrator of the system. I used this user for setting up the NAS (for everything that doesn’t have to be done as root) and I’m currently logged in as this user. There are also the following user groups: all-share (includes bob, joe, nas), media-share (includes bob, nas), joe (includes joe, nas) and bob (includes bob, nas).

Initially, I set `chown nas:media-share media` and `chown nas:all-share share`. I also set `chown joe:joe joe-personal` and `chown bob:bob bob-personal` and set `chmod 660 <foldername>` for all these folders. The shares were then configured like this:

```
[media]
    path = /srv/media
    comment = Media Share
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @media-share

[share]
    path = /srv/share
    comment = Common Share
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @all-share

[joe-personal]
    path = /srv/joe-personal
    comment = Personal Folder Joe
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @joe

[bob-personal]
    path = /srv/bob-personal
    comment = Personal Folder Bob
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @bob
```

Of course, I also added all these users to the Samba users DB. However, I wasn’t able to access any of these folders from any machine using any possible user account (Windows always says “You don’t have the permission to access …”).

I then added a line `force user = nas` to each share declaration, changed the ownership of each folder to nas:nas and changed the user permissions to 700. Now everything works like a charm!

The only problem is that obviously, all new files created in any of these folders are owned by nas, as opposed to the logged-in remote user that actually created them. This isn’t a massive problem for me, but it would still be really convenient to see who created what (for statistics, blaming, etc.). Does anyone have an idea why it wasn’t possible to access anything with the old configuration?

Here is a dump of my global configurations:

```
[global]
    server string = %h Samba NAS
    server role = standalone server
    security = USER
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    invalid users = root
```

System info: Ubuntu 16.04.02, up-to-date, Samba installed yesterday

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why you used the specification in the form: `valid users = @media-share`.  This is to specify group access: all users in the group `media-share`are valid users.    In your case, I would have used:
`valid users = joe` or `valid users = joe bob` if access is to be granted to both.  `write list` can also be used.  See the [manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) for more details.